# Z-index does not seem to work for React component

Tags: html, css

I have a html component that is showing up behind another one. I want it to be on the front of the other by using z-index...

HTML (React)

```
<div className="schedule">
            <div className="schedule-header">
                Horaire | Semaine du {getFormattedDayNumber(monday)} {getFormattedMonth(monday, true)}
            </div>
            <div className="schedule-body">
                <div className="schedule-days">
            {Object.keys(days).map((day, index) => (
                <div className="schedule-day">
                    <div className="day-header">
                        <span>{day} | {getFormattedDayNumber(getDateFromWeekMonday(monday, index))} {getFormattedMonth(getDateFromWeekMonday(monday, index))}</span>
                        {day.toLowerCase() === getFormattedWeekday(today) ? <span className="today">Aujourd'hui</span> : null}
                    </div>
                    <div className="day-body">
                        {days[day].map(task => (
                            <TaskComponent task={task} pixelsPerHour={pixelsPerHour} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400&display=swap');

.schedule {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 15px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.schedule-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Museo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0 20px 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* The arrow head */
.schedule-header::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 13px;
}

/* The arrow line */
.schedule-header::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}

.schedule-body {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: 2;
}

.schedule-days {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

.schedule-day {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.schedule-day:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid #f2f2f2; /* Ajoute une bordure à gauche pour le premier élément */
}

.day-header {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.day-body p {
    margin: 2px 2px 0 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: #6fe5eb;
    border-left: 5px solid #04B5CC;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


.today {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #04A9C4, #6FE5EB);
    padding: 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

As you can see in this code, I am trying to put the z-index of the schedule-header to be lower than the schedule-body to eventually have my ".today" in front of the header. I really am trying to make this work and it does not... What's the part I did not understand about z-index?

I have also found that we need to set the position of the parents for z-index to work, which is what is already done in my project.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A positioned element's `z-index` is relative to its stack level, not everything on the page.

Comment: So how could I make it show on top of the other page element (the schedule-header)?

Comment: Either put the `today` element inside the `schedule` element so it's relative to `schedule-header` and `schedule-body`, or set `.today`'s position to `fixed` which removes it from the DOM flow.